# Calculating bitwise inversion of char

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I am trying to reverse engineering a serial port device that uses hdlc for its packet format.Based on the documentation, the packet should contain a bitwise inversion  of the command(first 4 bytes), which in this case is `"HELO"`. Monitoring the serial port when using the original program shows what the bitwise inversion should be:

```
 HELO -> b7 ba b3 b0
 READ -> ad ba be bb
```

The problem is, I am not getting values even remotely close.

```
public object checksum
    {

        get
        {
            var cmdDec = (int)Char.GetNumericValue((char)this.cmd);
            return (cmdDec ^ 0xffffffff);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.cmd`, please? `String`, `byte[]`, `char[]`, something else?

Comment: this.cmd = HELO

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is not an `int` literal. It is either a `uint` or a `long`, depending on the context (in this case, it is a `long`). As such, the result of an `int` being XOR'd with a `long` will return a `long`. Also, if you're performing a bitwise inversion, you can use the `~` operator.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It can't be a string. If it were, this script wouldn't even compile. The fact that it does means that it's either a `char` or something castable to `char`.

Comment: Your `checksum` shouldn't be a property and it shouldn't have type `object`. Without quotes or brackets it's not clear what `this.cmd = HELO` means but it can't be true when `(char)this.cmd` compiles.

Comment: Create a [mcve] if you want to ask an answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to work with *bytes*, not with *chars*:

```
string source = "HELO";

// Encoding.ASCII: I assume that the command line has ASCII encoded commands only  
byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII
  .GetBytes(source)
  .Select(b => unchecked((byte)~b)) // unchecked: ~b returns int; can exceed byte.MaxValue
  .ToArray();
```

Test (let's represent the `result` as hexadecimals)

```
// b7 ba b3 b0
Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) is not a byte. You should use bytes instead of chars.

---

So `this.cmd` is an array of bytes? You could use the [`BitConverter.ToUInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

PSEUDO: *(you might fix some casting)*

```
public uint checksum
{
    get
    {
        var cmdDec = BitConverter.ToUInt32(this.cmd, 0);
        return (cmdDec ^ 0xffffffff);
    }
}
```

---

if `this.cmd` is a string you could get a byte array from it with [`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your bitwise inversion isn't doing what you think it's doing. Take the following, for example:

```
int i = 5;

var j = i ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
var k = ~i;
```

The first example is performing the inversion the way you are doing it, by XOR-ing the number with a max value. The second value uses the C# [Bitwise-NOT `~`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46zxf1c0(v=vs.100).aspx) operator.

After running this code, `j` will be a `long` value equal to 4294967290, while `k` will be an `int` value equal to -6. Their binary representation will be the same, but `j` will include another 32 bits of 0's to go along with it. There's also the obvious problem of them being completely different numbers, so any math performed on the values will be completely different depending on what you are using.